# change all timestamp columns in table to varbinary(8)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm creating an archive table using `SELECT INTO`. This table however has a time stamp column, and when I try to insert values I get the following error:

> Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column

I do not wish to insert using a column list, and then insert `null` to the TimeStamp column

What I want to do is on the archive table change dynamically all colums of type Timestamp to `varbinary(8)`.

What I have tried so far is to get the column:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'AppServices_Notification' AND 
     DATA_TYPE = 'TimeStamp'

ALTER TABLE AppServices_Notification
ALTER COLUMN COLUMN_NAME varbinary(8)
```

Is there a way to this in one action?

Comment: You could do the conversion on the `SELECT INTO`...  `SELECT Column1, CAST(Column2 AS VARBINARY(8)) AS Column2, Column3... FROM...`

Comment: see , in my question  . I do not to wish to do it like this because on every schema change I will also need to update this query